# How to change the eclipse hot key?

Tags: java, eclipse

In my machine, ctrl space is occupies by another program. How to chanhe this hot key in Eclipse?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Windows -> Preferences -> General -> Keys -> Content Assist command

Answer (score 2):

Windows --> Preferences -->

General --> Keys

You can filter out what you're looking for and assign the new hot key/s that way.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can change it in `Windows->Preferences`

Answer (score 0):

windows--->preferences--->General--->keys[image]